# Citation of newspaper articles for inclusion in a legal exhibit

Tags: united-states, evidence, civil-procedure, pro-se

I am preparing my exhibits for a special education impartial hearing.  The requirements are less stringent than for a court case.  If I can satisfy the requirements for a court case, I will be fine.  Problem: I'm not a lawyer and have no experience with court cases.

I want to include a newspaper article in my exhibits.  This particular newspaper has its archives freely available on the internet.  Shall I just print out the article, and put the url a little bit below the text?  Or is there a special way of citing a newspaper article?

**Edit 9/27/16:**

What I ended up doing was just printing the article (to a pdf) from the website.  Didn't have any problems doing it this way.

Comment: I looked at http://www.p12.nysed.gov/specialed/lawsregs/sect2005.htm and found nothing specific. I think the answer is, "do what everybody else does" – it is very unlikely that they will be obsessive about such details. However, I suggest giving a date, publication name, edition, section, page and article-citation. Things on the internet are suspicious and temporary and URLs are not worth squat, so show that it derives from something real and independently verifiable – a piece of paper. Permanence and traceability are probably low-priority, but it's classy.

Comment: Be sure to include a certification on your part as to the source and correctness of your copies.

Comment: @user3344003 - I don't understand.  Could you explain what that means?  I went to the website, hit "print", printed to a pdf -- what do you mean by my "copies"?  And what is "certification"?  Note that basically I just need to cite my source in a way that the opposing lawyer can verify so she won't dispute it.  But remember, in general the requirements are not as stringent as in a court of law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generally accepted legal citation format in the U.S. is the [Bluebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluebook).

Here is a website to help you generate the citation: [Citeus Legalus](http://citeuslegalus.com/cite/periodical).

As an example, here is how one would cite this New York Times article from today's paper called [Debt Collectors’ Abuses Prompt Consumer Agency to Propose New Rules](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/07/28/business/dealbook/debt-collectors-abuses-prompt-consumer-agency-to-propose-new-rules.html) that you accessed online.

Stacy Cowley, Debt Collectors’ Abuses Prompt Consumer Agency to Propose New Rules, 165 N.Y. Times, July 28, 2016, available at http://www.nytimes.com/2016/07/28/business/dealbook/debt-collectors-abuses-prompt-consumer-agency-to-propose-new-rules.html (last visited July 28, 2016).